# Google Authentication with Tornado

Tags: oauth, tornado

I'm trying to get google authentication working with Tornado to test the concept. I have the following code:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
import tornado.auth
import os.path
import time

from tornado.options import define, options

define("port",default=8000, help="run on port", type=int)

class AuthHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleMixin):

   @tornado.gen.coroutine
   def get(self):
      if self.get_argument('code', False):
         print("now running auth_user()")
         user = yield self.get_authenticated_user(
             redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000/auth',
             code=self.get_argument('code'))
         self.set_secure_cookie('token',"XXX")
         self.redirect('/')
      else:
         yield self.authorize_redirect(
             redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000/auth',
             client_id=self.settings['google_oauth']['key'],
             scope=['profile', 'email'],
             response_type='code',
             extra_params={'approval_prompt': 'force'})

 #  def post(self):
 #     self.render('index.html')


class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      token=self.get_secure_cookie('token')
      if not token:
         print("getting google token")
         self.redirect('/auth')
      else:
         print("TOKEN!")

 #  def post(self):
 #     self.render('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
   tornado.options.parse_command_line()
   H=[(r'/',IndexHandler),(r'/auth',AuthHandler)]
   T=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"templates")
   settings=dict(
      google_oauth = dict(key="XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com", secret ="YYYYY"),
      cookie_secret = 'DPTDQARHTDayv8WV61iMSsvAD18Rc00bizO519+2i4w='
   )

   app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=H,template_path=T,debug=True, **settings)

   http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
   http_server.listen(options.port)
   tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I keep getting a

```
"TypeError: authorize_redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'client_id'"
```

I followed the documentation around getting the client ID and secret and put those values in the settings. Also I have set the redirect URI within the google console to be `'localhost:8000/auth'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be

```
class AuthHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleOAuth2Mixin):
```